# \Zend\Barcode generates wrong barcodes

Tags: zend-framework, barcode

using \Zend\Barcode (ZF 2.3.1) I'm not able to produce a readable barcode.
I've attached the picture generated (inside a PDF) by Zend Framework's tool.
[image: generated barcode]

The original text was `00000001C` and the factory is `code39`. I've tried with `code128` but same problem.
For some reason, my Motorola LS2208 can not recognize this barcode.
The specs of this scanner tells it should !

An other strange thing is all "code 39" or "code 128" generated on http://www.barcoding.com/upc/ are different from the ones produced by ZF.

I'm quite new to barcode generation and I just don't have any clue of what are the possible reason of this to fails. Can someone bring me some light here ?
Is the generated barcode correct, at least ?
The ZF documentation about specific renderers is very light...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally found an answer to this.
First, I was generating barcodes with a width of 2cm.
This is really too tiny for 9 characters using the code 39 symbols.

The screenshot I've taken was made zooming on the PDF ; it shows a code where vertical bars were overlapping themselves.

Basically the solution is : NEVER EVER provide a 'factor' value lower than 1 to `BarcodeZF::factory()`, because this is what have makes bars overlap.

Comment: in order to make this post useful for people, I changed the question title, from "Reading \Zend\Barcode with Motorola LS2208" to "\Zend\Barcode generates wrong barcodes", as LS2208 isn't even involve in my problem.